# Lucene near real time search

Tags: java, lucene, near-real-time

I am using Lucene 6.6.0 and I would like to use the near real-time search feature of Lucene. However, I could not manage to implement it. The way I try to get the feature is as follows:

I initialize an IndexReader instance:

```
this.reader = DirectoryReader.open(this.directory);
```

Let's assume some changes have been made in the index via an IndexWriter instance. Then, if I understand correctly, I need a second instance of IndexReader to commit updates:

```
this.newReader = DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(this.reader);
if (this.newReader != null) {
    // Update the IndexSearcher with the new IndexReader instance
    this.searcher = new IndexSearcher(this.newReader);
    this.reader.close();
}
```

The issue here is that the code does not compile because of the following error: `The method openIfChanged(DirectoryReader) in the type DirectoryReader is not applicable for the arguments (IndexReader)`.

How should I update the `IndexReader` then ?

Secondly, if I update the index again, I will need another IndexReader instance, won't I ? Would the most optimal way to update the index freely during the execution of the program be by switching between 2 IndexReader instances after each update ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use a SearcherManager instead of a IndexReader:
http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/SearcherManager.html

Based on the SearcherManager your able to execute following methods:

```
// get a IndexSearcher for searching
IndexSearcher searcher = searcherManager.aquire();

// release IndexSearcher after search
searcherManager.release(searcher);

// refresh and add new index records to next search. usually after a commit 
searcherManager.maybeRefresh();
```

I tried to implement this as well and basically i did this:

- create an IndexWriter and leave it open
- create a SearcherManager with the IndexWriter as param.
- use SearcherManager to search
- use IndexWriter for indexing operations.
- commit after indexing

Additionally you can use a separate thread to commit periodically and not on every write because the commit operation may be pretty "expensive".

Example here: http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-nrt-hello-world.html

Comment: I did as you said and it seems to work well. When some changes occur, I call 
    
    this.writer.maybeMerge();
    this.writer.commit();
    this.searcherManager.maybeRefresh();

These 3 lines are necessary to be able to search in the updated index, aren't they ?

I prefer to refresh the index manually by calling these methods after indexing instead of using a thread, because in my case indexing occurs only in the beginning, so there is no need to refresh it regularly. Using a thread to refresh the index would be optimal when the index is dynamic, wouldn't it ?

Comment: commit and maybeRefresh are necessary yes. not sure if maybeMerge is really needed but you have to check that.
hmm hang on, why do you wanna implement a NRT use case if you only index once? you don't have any changes on the index after initial indexing?

Comment: Technically, no, but I am only indexing documents belonging to certain file types. When I execute my program and new file types can also be indexed, I do not want to construct the index from scratch but to update the existing one with new documents. I also want the ability to update the index even after the initial update in case I may need it later.

Comment: ok thats fine. in this case a NRT implementation is usefull. According to your question: The dedicated thread makes sense in case if you have a lot of changes in small time delta. in this case doing a commit can lock other threads because they have to wait till commit is done. so in this case it would make sense to have a dedicated thread which is commiting like every 5 seconds for example.