# Lucene pagination using searchAfter while index is updated

Tags: lucene

I have implemented pagination with Lucene using the `searchAfter` method provided by `IndexSearcher`. In every call, I pass the last `ScoreDoc` returned in the previous page.

The problem is that sometimes, the index gets updated between page and page and occasionally I am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: after.doc exceeds the number of 
documents in the reader: after.doc=337 limit=337
    at 
org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.searchAfter(IndexSearcher.java:434)
```

I understand that Lucene changes the docs ids every now and then (segment merges, etc.) and I guess that is why that exception is happening as `searchAfter` relies on those docs ids.

How could I improve this pagination mechanism to avoid this exception? Is there any better way to implement pagination with Lucene?

Comment: how many times you see this problem occurs? like how many times you get index updates while searching

Comment: @dom no very often. I have implemented some tests that update the index (delete and/or update documents) during searching and many time it doesn't fail. It depends on when Lucene changes those docs internally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this error but i would suggest to implement a way you can use NRT (Near real time) searches with a SearcherManager ([JavaDoc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/SearcherManager.html))

it's a big effort but at the end you receive a better update handling for indices especially if they update more frequently.

See:
[Lucene NRT beginner tutorial](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-nrt-hello-world.html) or [related stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275557/lucene-near-real-time-search)

Comment: Actually I am using NRT and SearcherManager. I acquire a SearcherManager when a new page needs to be fetched and then I call searchAfter(...).

Comment: do you use maybeRefresh() after indexing?